# Fetching relational data Android Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having a table structure like this trying to fetch multiple data all those related tables-

[image]

I have list of category (**ProfileCateGory Object**) and inside every category list (**ProfileData Object**) of profile Date with the there view count (**ProfileViewCount Object**)

I am new to this Parse.com I tried like this -

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ProfileData");
    query.whereEqualTo("profileName", "Profile");

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < query.count(); i++) {
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (object == null) {
                        Log.d("ProfileData", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Name: " + object.get("profileName").toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }
```

I am getting only one data from ProfileData.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [relational-queries](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-relational-queries)

For that you have to make `profileCode` as Pointer type in `ProfileViewCounts`

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("ProfileData");
innerQuery.whereEqualTo("profileName", "Profile");

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =ParseQuery.getQuery("ProfileViewCounts");
    query.whereMatchesQuery("profileCode", innerQuery);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject objProfileViewCounts, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as you can see I have basically 3 table. You have joined ProfileData and ProfileViewCounts. But how can I join ProfileCateGory with ProfileData?

Comment: user `bolt` library which supported by `parse.com` for this type of problem [BoltsFramework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#chaining-tasks-together)

Answer (score 0):

getFirstInBackground() is to call and return just one item.

To get an array or more objets you need to do:

```
            //profile or id of user , you have to pass as a parameter

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ProfileData");
            query.whereEqualTo("profileName", Profile);

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {


                    if (e == null) {

                        for (int inP = 0; inP < objects.size(); inP++) {

                            String profileName = objects.get(inP).getString("profileName");


                        }


                    } else {

                    }


                }
```